# How to detect that user typed Command-Up Arrow in UITextView on iOS with external keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview

I have a UITextView in an iOS app for the user to type in.  I customize it in order to add custom behavior, including a "typewriter mode" where the current line of text stays centered vertically on screen.

If the user has an external keyboard and types "Command-Up Arrow", the selection moves to beginning of the text, but I need to handle the scrolling myself, because I have overridden the default behavior.

If the user types text, this is handled as part of changes made via the `insertText:` method.

If the user types a regular arrow key (up/down/left/right), I detect this by overriding `positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset`.

But I don't see what method is used after typing "Command-Up Arrow".  On macOS, I believe this would be handled via `moveToBeginningOfDocument:`.  What is the equivalent method called on iOS?

Searching did not lead me to an answer (perhaps poor search terms).  Breaking on `textviewDidChangeSelection:` in Xcode doesn't show anything useful -- it shows `[UITextView textinputDidChangeSelection:]` followed by `UIApplicationMain` after skipping 46 intermediate methods....

I realize I could create my own UICommandKey, but it would probably be better to react to the default behavior instead of overriding it unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks for any help!